# Can`t switch video from normal size

Tags: actionscript-3

I imported the video into the project, that includes another videos in nomall size.
How to toggle the embedded video from normal predefined size to full screen and back with ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your video is in a movie clip. So you could simply add a button to the stage and add a listener to it. Then the code within the listener would look like this:

```
boolFullScreen = !boolFullScreen
if (boolFullScreen == true)
{
     mcVideo.width = stage.width;
     mcVideo.height = stage.height;
}
else
{
     mcVideo.width = 1920;
     mcVideo.height = 1080;
}
```

The 1920x1080 is just an example.

Hope this helps